# Accessing MotionEvent on keyboard in Java (android)

Tags: java, android, events, touch

Im trying to read MotionEvents in my app to get how hard the users press on their keyboards, the problem is MotionEvents doesnt fire on the keyboard but on the rest of the app. I have tried with the onTouchEvent and it actually works in the app with getting pressure from the touchevent. Does anybody have any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write your own soft keyboard (technically called an "input method editor") in order to get touch events for the soft keyboard.